# Unity AR Foundation AR Tracked Image Manager gives blank screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm just starting out in AR Development Using Unity and AR Foundation. I want to track a simple image. So I did the following steps:

1)Created the Reference Image Library and added a picture.

2)Added the AR Tracked Image Manager component in AR Session Origin.

3)Linked the reference Library accordingly.

When building into Android, all I see is a black screen. When I removed the reference library in the component, the camera works.

Additionally, I put a white sphere in front of the AR camera(when the camera was not wokking), and the white sphere does render on a black background.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Upgrade your project with URP (Universal Render Pipeline).
Then Create new renderer asset (Right click on Project->Create->Rendering-> Universal render pipeline-> Pipeline Asset).

Assign this pipeline asset to the Graphics tab in Project Settings.

Upgrade your project's material to URP material. (Goto Edit menu-> Render Pipeline -> Universal render pipeline-> upgrade project material to UniversalRP material).

Then the most important point is to Select that created render pipeline asset, see its properties in the Inspector tab, select forward render pipeline (which is automatically created with this pipeline asset).

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSkqe.png)

You will see like the above image, and then click on Add Renderer Feature, and add AR Background Renderer feature.

Build your project and test it.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I religiously followed the steps you said, but Add Renderer Feature did not show add AR Background Renderer Feature.

Comment: Try this, Upgrade your ARFoundation version to the latest, Also ARCore/ARKit plugin from Package Manager.